# Parse.Query and-combination issue

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfquery

In cloud code, I made a query using this sort of code:

```
theMainQuery = new Parse.Query("myClass");
theMainQuery.equalTo("fieldOne", "champion");

theSubQuery = new Parse.Query("myClass");
theSubQuery.equalTo("fieldTwo", "USA");

the2ndSubQuery = new Parse.Query("myClass");
the2ndSubQuery.equalTo("fieldTwo", "BRASIL");

theSubQuery = Parse.Query.or(theSubQuery,the2ndSubQuery);

theMainQuery = Parse.Query.and(theMainQuery,theSubQuery);
```

In other words I want a query based on this condition:

```
((fieldOne equals "champion") and ((fieldTwo equals "USA") or (fieldTwo equals "BRASIL")))
```

In usual C style writing I want to select records matching:

```
((fieldOne == "champion") && ((fieldTwo == "USA") || (fieldTwo == "BRASIL")))
```

The problem is that it does not work, I suppose my `Parse.Query.and` is wrong. Then how can I get the result I want?

Of course, I would be happy to avoid reformulating the query in this long format:

```
 (((fieldOne == "champion") && (fieldTwo == "USA")) || ((fieldOne == "champion") && (fieldTwo == "BRASIL")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so what you want to do can be done within one Query object.

I feel what your looking for is 'containedIn'... So you specify the key 'fieldTwo' and pass in an array of values to 'or' with.

So heres what I think it should look like, I implemented this in Objective-C but not javascript. but heres my javascript version

```
var query = new Parse.Query('myclass');
query.equalTo('fieldOne', 'champion');
query.containedIn('fieldTwo', ['USA', 'Brazil']);
query.find();
```

I hope this was what your looking for... By the way, I was able to find this in the docs, https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries. There docs are very helpful but sometimes doesn't help me :P

Comment: From my experience, I typically only use 'or' queries when I have to join one query with another, where the other one uses 'matchesQuery'. But thats just from my experience. Idk, maybe there are other reasons. There probably are that I've used I just can't think of them right now :P

Comment: Indeed you are right. I was too quick seeing the doc, though I also looked at it. Many thanks.